# Why there's not listed rootfs in /proc/mounts?

Tags: systemd-mount

I have a running server but there's no rootfs in `/proc/mounts`. Why? How to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `cat` to view the file?

`/proc/mounts` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/mounts`

The following commands will show you `rootfs`

`cat /proc/mounts | grep rootfs`

`cat /proc/self/mounts | grep rootfs`

If you run it without `grep`, it will show all of your mounts.

Comment: There's no rootfs in /proc/self/mounts either. Someone told me, there no longer rootfs in  /proc/mounts...

Comment: Is there no rootfs when you `cat` the file? What distro are you running?